# How can I check whether my list contains a string with a certain condition

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there can be written something like this:

```
List<string> list;
string sub;
if( list.Contains( s=>s.Contains(sub) ) ) {
    //do something
}
```

what I want here in the code is to see if the `list<string> list` contains `string s` with a certain substring `string sub` which I would previously set to a value

thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it can be done using linq

```
list.Where(s => s.Contains(sub))
```

this gives you a list with all strings containing the substring.

If you just want to check if any of the strings contains the substring, you can use the method `Any`

```
if (list.Any(s => s.Contains(sub))) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below

```
var newList = list.Where(x=>x.Contains(sub)).ToList();
if(newList != null && newList.Count> 0){
   //Do something here
}
```

it will return the list of string contains sub

Comment: Contains is written with capital letter in the beginning ;), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

`list.Contains("foo")`, in this code the  `Enumerable.Contains` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains) checks if the list contains the specified element. An exact match.

What you want is either :

1/. Select the elements that match a sub pattern : 
[Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where)

```
var elementsWithSubPattern = list.Where(s => s.Contains(sub));
```

2/. Check if there are any element in this list that match the sub pattern:  [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any)

```
bool anyMatch = list.Any(s => s.Contains(sub));
```

3/. Check if all the elements match the sub pattern: 
[All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all)

```
bool allMatch = list.All(s => s.Contains(sub));
```